# Calling a function in Agda

Tags: function, functional-programming, agda, agda-mode

I have this code which is basically a hello world, with an addition function, it compiles and runs and outputs 'Hello, world 5!':

```
open import Common.IO

data  ℕ  : Set  where
 zero  : ℕ
 suc   : ℕ → ℕ

-- how to call a function in agda i.e. '_+_(5, 4)' to get '9' 

_+_   :  ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
zero + m = m
suc n + m = suc (n  + m)


main = putStrLn "Hello, world 5!"
```

How do I call my `_+_` function? My goal is to call `_+_` with two arguments like `_+_(3,4)` and get the program to output seven.

My intuition says to replace the line ' `main = putStrLn "Hello, world 5!"`' with something like '`putStrLn _+_(3,4)`'

I'm new to Agda, and there aren't many examples online of working code. Can anybody get this function working by giving a practical code example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open import Common.IO
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ; zero; suc)
open import Data.Integer using (ℤ; +_; show)
open import Data.String using (_++_)

_+_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
zero  + m = m
suc n + m = suc (n + m)

main = putStrLn ("Hello, world " ++ show (+ (3 + 4)) ++ "!")
```

Comment: This code compiles and runs on my macheine! Thank you!